# How to query a field in a user defined type in a Set

Tags: cassandra, set, cqlsh, user-defined-types

I'm using cassandra 5.1 and I want to query a field in a user defined type in a Set.

There is my type which I created:

```
CREATE TYPE public.fluxes (
    filter_name text,
    flux float,
    flux_prec smallint,
    flux_error float,
    flux_error_prec smallint,
    flux_qual text, 
    flux_var text,
    flux_mult text,
    flux_bibcode text,
    system text
);
```

And I want to only get the `filter_name` field
What I'm supposed to do for getting this filed?

Comment: You can't select partial field from `UDT`. You have to select the full UDT

Comment: Then it is possible to select only 1 object from a set ? For exemple, the object at the position 0 ?